# Haproxy redirect and fowarding the subdomain

Tags: haproxy

I have an Haproxy server and I need when the user type **any_word**.registro.myserver.com.br on the browser, the Haproxy redirect to https://app2.otherserver.com.br/register/**any_word**

The **any_word** is a captcha (*.registro.myserver.com.br)

Today I have the following redirect that doesn't forward:

```
acl fqdn_register_all hdr_dom(host) -i registro.myserver.com.br
redirect prefix https://app2.otherserver.com.br/register code 302 if fqdn_register_all
```

How should i change the above code?

Best regards

Answer (score 2):

this rule should do the work:

```
acl fqdn_register hdr_dom(host) -i registro.myserver.com.br
capture request header Host len 128
redirect prefix https://app2.otherserver.com.br/register/%[capture.req.hdr(0)] code 302 if fqdn_register
```

hope it helps.

Comment: The rule above do not substitute the var and redirected the browser to: https://app2.otherserver.com.br/register/%[capture.req.hdr(0)]/ 

Any ideia? Best regards